# How to know if two objects are comparable to each other?

Tags: java, comparable

I would like to write universal comparator, which can compare objects of any class. I would like numbers go first, then strings, then all other comparable objects.

First I wrote

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                if( o1 instanceof Number && !(o2 instanceof Number) ) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if( o2 instanceof Number && !(o1 instanceof Number) ) {
                    return +1;
                }
                else if( o1 instanceof String && !(o2 instanceof String) ) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if( o2 instanceof String && !(o1 instanceof String) ) {
                    return +1;
                }
                else if( o1 instanceof Comparable && !(o2 instanceof Comparable) ) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if( o2 instanceof Comparable && !(o1 instanceof Comparable) ) {
                    return +1;
                }
                else if( o1 instanceof Comparable && o2 instanceof Comparable ) {
                    return ((Comparable)o1).compareTo(o2);
                }
                else {
                    return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();
                }
            }
```

I was thinking the check

```
o1 instanceof Comparable && o2 instanceof Comparable
```

will give me comparing within numbers, strings and all other comparable classes.

But then I found that `Number` is not comparable, i.e. I can't compare doubles with integers with it.

Also I found, that `Comparable<T>` contract is fuzzy. Although `T` can be any class, actually it probably should be the same class which implements it...

So, how to accomplish?

Comment: _I would like to write universal comparator_ You'll always have cases that you haven't handled correctly or at all. It will cause you more headaches than it will solve problems.

Comment: There is no proper way to do this because it's not really possible.

Comment: So what is the answer to the title question?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose sometime in the future you create some instances of class Apple and the some instances of class Orange.  How could the universal comparison algorithm that you write today possibly compare those Apple instances to the Orange instances in the future?  I think you need to rethink what you are trying to accomplish and perhaps make sure your objects are of the same class before trying to compare them.